# How to retrieve constructor・instance initializer・static initializer as methods?

Tags: java, reflection, methods

As far as I understood, constructors, instance initializers and static initializers are just methods with special names. I know that `<` and `>` are illegal characters for ordinary identifiers.
How can I retrieve these special methods as `Method` objects (or something equivalent) and call them? You might take a look at this code snippet I wrote:

```
public class Program {
    /**
     * static <init>() {
     * }
     */
    static {
    }

    /**
     * <init>() {
     * }
     */
    {
    }

    /**
     * <cinit>() {
     * }
     */
    Program(){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        //get native getDeclaredMethods method
        Method Class$getDeclaredMethods0 = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("getDeclaredMethods0", boolean.class);
        Class$getDeclaredMethods0.setAccessible(true);

        //list methods of this class
        Method[] methods = (Method[])Class$getDeclaredMethods0.invoke(Program.class, false);
        for (Method m : methods) {
            System.out.println(m);
        }

        //Console output:
        /*
        public static void dirty.Program.main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException

         */
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Java 7+? If yes you can use `MethodHandle`s to invoke constructors, however not static initializers

Comment: I use Java 7, but if you have a solution for Java 8 ready, you could let me know, too.

Comment: How do I use them? Do instance initializers work?

Comment: No, instance initializers won't work either, but anyway they are executed by the constructor itself; and it does not really make sense to invoke one without the constructor. Out of curiosity, what is your goal here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You can get `Constructor` instances for the declared constructors, but there is no Java type that represents an invocable static or instance initializer.

Comment: I highly suspect this. At least with Javassist this *should* be possible.

Comment: Well, starting with Java 7 you can get `MethodHandle`s out of these

Comment: @fge And you can execute them?

Comment: @fge Then I will review. Thanks.

Comment: @fge I meant for initializers.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've misread that part, but no, you can't do that. MethodHandle.Lookup needs a name.

Answer (score 0):

Static initializers you cannot. As to instance initializers, they are executed by the constructor, and it does not really make sense to execute one without the associated constructor (they require the instance to exist after all).

Since Java 7 and java.lang.invoke you can use `MethodHandle`s for constructors. You'll invoke them in the same manner as regular methods. For instance, this is an extract of code I use to build instances of exceptions (note: Java 8):

```
private static final Lookup LOOKUP
    = MethodHandles.publicLookup();

// Method type for a constructor accepting a Throwable as an argument
private static final MethodType TYPE
    = MethodType.methodType(void.class, Throwable.class);

private MethodHandle getHandle(final Class<? extends RuntimeException> c)
{
    return handles.computeIfAbsent(c, key -> {
        try {
            return LOOKUP.findConstructor(c, TYPE)
                .asType(TYPE.changeReturnType(RuntimeException.class));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new InstantiationException(e);
        }
    });
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <E extends RuntimeException> E get(final Class<E> c,
    final Throwable t)
{
    try {
        return (E) getHandle(c).invokeExact(t);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.addSuppressed(t);
        throw e;
    } catch (Error | RuntimeException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Throwable oops) {
        final RuntimeException exception = new InstantiationException(oops);
        exception.addSuppressed(t);
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lambdas got introduced with Java 8

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that the code was Java 8. java.lang.invoke however has been there since Java 7.